# Vuetify how can I disable button till all validation rules are true?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify to create a simple form where the data is being validated by some rules associated with each field. What I am trying to do is disable the Submit button if any of those validation rules fails. How can I do so? What I am trying to understand is how to check the state of each rule so that I can bind the `disabled` property on the button.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-combobox
        v-model="addTool.name"
        :rules="rules.name"
        :items="toolNames"
        counter
        label="Name of the tool"
      ></v-combobox>
      <v-combobox
        multiple
        :small-chips="true"
        :deletable-chips="true"
        :hide-selected="true"
        :clearable="true"
        v-model="addTool.categories"
        :rules="rules.categories"
        label="Select/Add categories"
        :items="this.toolCategories"
        :search-input.sync="searchCat"
        @change="searchCat = ''"
      ></v-combobox>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="addTool.site"
        label="URL for the tool. It is best to use a Github repo link."
        :rules="rules.site"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn @click="submit" color="grey darken-4" class="green--text text--accent-2" dark>Add</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      searchCat: "",
      addToolMessage: undefined,
      addTool: {
        name: "",
        categories: [],
        created_on: "",
        site: ""
      },
      rules: {
        name: [
          v => !!v || "Required.",
          v => v.length < 80 || "Name is too long",
          v =>
            !this.toolsData
              .map(n => n.name.toLowerCase())
              .includes(v.toLowerCase()) || "This tool already exists"
        ],
        categories: [v => v.length != 0 || "At least one category is needed"],
        site: [
          v => !!v || "Required.",
          v =>
            new RegExp(
              "^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:S+(?::S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:.d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169.254|192.168)(?:.d{1,3}){2})(?!172.(?:1[6-9]|2d|3[0-1])(?:.d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]d?|1dd|2[01]d|22[0-3])(?:.(?:1?d{1,2}|2[0-4]d|25[0-5])){2}(?:.(?:[1-9]d?|1dd|2[0-4]d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})).?)(?::d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]S*)?$",
              "ig"
            ).test(v) || "Not a valid URL",
          v =>
            !this.toolsData.map(u => u.site).includes(v) ||
            "This tool already exists"
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: A silly mistake, but I've had `v-bind` instead of `v-model` on <v-form.../>... I made the mistake while migrating from `Vue2`/`Nuxt2`/`Vuetify2` to `Vue2`/`Nuxt2`/`Vuetify2`, because `v-hover` now wants `v-bind` on nested `v-card`, which wasn't the case before, and I must have been automatically changed it in `v-form` as well in the massive migration. Maybe it'll help somebody, adding just as a comment :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Vuetify will track the validity of form if you wrap input elements in `v-form` and then attach v-model to `form` like this:

```html
<v-form v-model="isFormValid">
  <!-- all input elements go here -->
</v-form>

<!-- disable if form is not valid -->
<v-btn :disabled="!isFormValid">Add</v-btn>
```

You also need to add `isFormValid` to the component's `data` field:

```js
data: () => ({
  isFormValid: false,
})
```

You can read more here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms

Comment: but how do i map isFormValid to the rules array is the question

Comment: You don't have to.

`isFormValid` has its value set by vuetify, to true, when all validation rules return true.

Comment: @ManishRaj  This works! But I couldn't find this in the docs, where is it?

Comment: But by default Submit button is enabled until you click on some field to verify. By default Submit should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed property do to it. Lets say `name` and `site` are requireds, so:

```html
<temlate>
  <v-btn :disabled="isAddButtonDisabled" @click="submit" color="grey darken-4" class="green--text text--accent-2" dark>Add</v-btn>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      addTool: {
        name: "",
        categories: [],
        created_on: "",
        site: ""
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isAddButtonDisabled() {
      return !(this.addTool.name || this.addTool.site);
      // means u have neither name nor site  
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If you need to check if form is valid, you can do:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    formValid () {
      // loop over all contents of the fields object and check if they exist and valid.
      return Object.keys(this.addTool).every(field => {
        return this.addTool[field] && this.addTool[field].valid;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

From here: https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/853

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, your solution doesnt answer my question. In your solution, the isAddButtonDisabled will return true as long as there is data in those properties. Not check if they are validated or not.

Comment: Sorry! Edited my answer

Comment: ah, the question is how to map this to the array of validating functions. There is not valid property in the data structure as you can see

Comment: in this case you can check `this.errors.count() > 0`