# Vuetify with multiple forms in a page. Disable submit button on each form till validation rules criteria is met on that form

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

If I have a single form I was able to do disable/enable of submit button on that form using the below code.

But how do I achieve this if I have multiple forms ? Vuetify has this option or should I write some code to achieve on my own ?

[How to achieve this if we have a single form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793226/vuetify-how-can-i-disable-button-till-all-validation-rules-are-true)

HTML part

```
<v-form v-model="isFormValid">
  <!-- all input elements go here -->
</v-form>

<!-- disable if form is not valid -->
<v-btn :disabled="!isFormValid">Add</v-btn>
```

In script

```
data: () => ({
  isFormValid: false,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a different v-model value for each v-form? Do you have an undetermined number of forms?

If you need to check all validity, you can create a computed data/method that checks all of them.

```
computed: {
  allValid() {
    return this.validFormContact && this.validFormPreferences;
  }
}
```