# How to disable vuetify form submit button until all the validation rules are full-filled

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have found the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793226/vuetify-how-can-i-disable-button-till-all-validation-rules-are-true/57827717) in this platform. Based on the accepted answer, I have built a form and made my button disabled.

```
<v-btn :disabled="!isFormValid">submit</v-btn>

data: () => ({
  isFormValid: false,
})
```

But, Whenever, I filled an input, the submit button would activated though all other inputs are empty!

[image]

So, what is the actual way to keep the button `disabled` until all the inputs are not empty?

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/eYeOvYx)

Comment: remove `lazy-validation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `lazy-validation` property. As per the documentation,

> If `lazy-validation` is enabled, [**value**(A boolean value representing the validity of the
> form.)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props) will always be true unless there are visible validation
> errors

Comment: That usually isn't a problem if in your submit button function you call `this.$refs.myFormRef.validate()`.